# Android - How to create invisible camera preview for video recording?

Tags: android, camera

I want to create hidden SurfaceView for camera preview. I tried method recommended in answer to another question:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);        
wm.addView(surfaceview, params);

surfaceview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

but it isn't invisible, in fact it takes the whole screen. I tried setting alpha or resizing it but it doesn't work. Is there a way to making it hidden or at least resizing it to 1x1 size?

**EDIT:**

I would also add that simply placing 1x1 `SurfaceView` in activity layout wouldn't work in my case because I use multiple layouts and I believe `Views` are destroyed on layout change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SurfaceView` is taking up the whole screen because your code defines the width/height to be `WRAP_CONTENT`. Try using

```
new LayoutParams(1, 1, LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
```

To make hidden camera or similar stuff, you should not use the `Context` from your current `Activity` because your activity needs to be visible during recording (so this is not hidden...). When the current activity to put to background, the context will be `null` and the recording will stop or crash.

You may try running a `Service` (non-visible but also has a context) and create a `SurfaceView` from code in that service.